# Best way to refresh ListView when data in cursor hasn’t changed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with attached custom CursorAdapter. Within the CursorAdapter bindView method I run some calculations that depend on user’s chosen display units (these can be changed at any time in Settings)

Normally to update a ListView I would run:

```
myCursor = DB.getData();
myDataAdapter.changeCursor(myCursor);
```

This works fine in most cases. But if user changed their display units in Settings, above code doesn’t update the ListView. I assume this is because data in the cursor hasn’t actually changed.

I tried running `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` against the adapter, also `invalidateViews()` against the ListView, but none of this make any difference.
What I currently do is recreate the adapter:

```
myCursor = db.getData();
myCursorAdapter = new myCursorAdapter(getActivity(),myCursor,0);
myListView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

This works, but I don’t think it’s a good practice to re-create the adapter every time I need to refresh ListView... Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

`myDataAdapter.changeCursor(myCursor)` is actually working even when data in cursor hasn't changed. It was my own mistake in the Custom Cursor Adapter code that caused listview not to update unless adaptor was re-created.

`notifyDataSetChanged()` still doesn't work, but decided not to look into this further and just use `changeCursor`

Comment: you can do notifydatasetChanged in the activity, that might work.

Comment: Honestly I would just recreate my adapter in that situation. It would be the least messy way of guaranteeing your adapter is refreshing. No tracking booleans or anything like that. Really shouldn't bog your app down as long as it isn't something you do like 10 times a second.

Answer (score 0):

The BaseAdapter method [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) should do what you want. It could be that the adapter you are passing in is not the same as the adapter the ListView is using. Try using [getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter()) instead:

```
((MyCursorAdapter) myListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `myListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` returns "cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged()". I can get it to work by changing to `((MyCursorAdapter) myListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` But it still doesn't refresh ListView... Actually `notifyDataSetChanged()` has never worked for me, even when data in cursor changes.

Comment: Are you sure the list isn't being updated? What logic do you use to change the display units?

Comment: Thanks, that comment was helpful. `notifyDataSetChanged()` still doesn't work, but I managed to get `changeCursor(myCursor)` working! I double checked logic inside my custom CursorAdapter and found that I was assigning display units variables in the constructor, so they were never updated unless object was re-created. Still not sure why `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work, but I guess that would be another question...

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out!